# Web data scraping html table Excel VBA

Tags: html, vba

I have no problems getting data from a table on the webpage, but I bumped into two issues.

On the webpage, it only shows one page of table data, at the bottom I can click page 2, 3 and NEXT. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to see the html codes, I can see all information are loaded and neatly organised as tr rows.

I assume `ie.document` can store all elements, as what I can see using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in Chrome. And when I try to retrieve the tr innertext by using `getelementByTagName("tr")`, vba just skipped all tr elements which is supposed to be on other pages of the table. Pardon me if I don't explain well, and I couldn't paste the link and html codes here as it may contain confidential information. I wonder if someone ever bumped into similar issues.

```
ieDoc = ieApp.Document

For Each HTMLRow In ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")

Debug.print HTMLRow.innertext
```

Comment: you should have looked into the docs before posting the question here see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment yet, I hope the following helps at least a little.

To obtain the entire set of elements, you have to define a variable like so:

```
Dim variableName as IHTMLElementCollection
```

To return the collection:

```
Set variableName = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

In order to use the above, make sure to add the Reference Microsoft Internet Controls under Tools > References.

I asked a similar question in the past which might give you a larger example of how this works [Excel VBA getElementsByTagName](http://Excel%20VBA%20getElementsByTagName%20-%20Runtime%20error%20-%20424/%22here%22)

Comment: Thanks mate, I've tried this and looped through the collection, and it didnt return the tr elements i need, which is on page 2 or beyond of the table on the webpage. However all elements are loaded as i can see from the page source code.

Comment: Does page 2 have a distinct URL to peg off of? Else, you can try to hit the "next page" button if there is one. If the number of pages changed depending on the initial input, you can use the LocationURL method to verify that you are in the correct page. If you do find an answer, could you post it? I use these tools a lot and having different examples really helps a lot.

Comment: page doesnt have a distinct URL, when i press NEXT it wont direct to a new URL. My guess is the ie.document only records the tr rows as the screen is showing, not all tr rows as it contains in the full source code of the page.

Comment: And sure i will post the solution if i find one.